# iOS SDK generated by AWS API Gateway is missing required 'defaultClient' member

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've followed two API Gateway tutorials for two different REST APIs that call AWS Lambda. Here's the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) to the Calc API, which is the subject of this post.

In each case, test invocations via the AWS Console work perfectly. But when I generate the iOS Swift SDK from the deployed stage 'SDK Generation' tab, unzip and import into my Xcode project, the `defaultClient` member is missing in `<API-Name>Client.swift`.

The README.md file in each case says it should be there:

```
# Use the SDK in your project

1. Grab the `defaultClient` from your code

        let client = <API-Name>Client.defaultClient()

1. You can now call your method using the client SDK
```

But there is NO `defaultClient` in `<API-Name>Client.swift`.

**UPDATE**
There is no `defaultClient`, but there is a `default` (with backticks around it because `default` is a reserved word in Swift). So I substituted that in the REST API invocation... and it worked! I have no idea why... I don't know what the backticks mean in Swift... and if someone can explain this to me, great. But I verified via API Gateway that the API was called successfully; and I verified via Cloudwatch that the Lambda function returns the correct value.

Here is my code that invokes the API:

```
@IBAction func userInvokeApi(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("You clicked invoke api...")
    let client = SVTLambdaGateClient.default()
    client.calcGet(operand2: "3", _operator: "+", operand1: "5").continueWith{ (task: AWSTask?) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task?.error {
            print("Error occurred: \(error)")
            return nil
        }

        if let result = task?.result {
            // Do something with result
            print("The result is... \(result)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

However, I don't understand the data structure returned at the Client yet. This is what I get:

```
You clicked invoke api...
The result is... <AmplifyRestApiTest.Empty: 0x600002020770> {
}
```

Here are the full contents of the generated `<API-Name>Client.swift` file (with some comments removed). I'm thinking it's possible that the README is no longer in sync with the SDK generation.

```
import AWSCore
import AWSAPIGateway

public class SVTLambdaGateClient: AWSAPIGatewayClient {

    static let AWSInfoClientKey = "SVTLambdaGateClient"

    private static let _serviceClients = AWSSynchronizedMutableDictionary()
    private static let _defaultClient:SVTLambdaGateClient = {
        var serviceConfiguration: AWSServiceConfiguration? = nil
        let serviceInfo = AWSInfo.default().defaultServiceInfo(AWSInfoClientKey)
        if let serviceInfo = serviceInfo {
            serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: serviceInfo.region, credentialsProvider: serviceInfo.cognitoCredentialsProvider)
        } else if (AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration != nil) {
            serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration
        } else {
            serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .Unknown, credentialsProvider: nil)
        }

        return SVTLambdaGateClient(configuration: serviceConfiguration!)
    }()

    /**
     Returns the singleton service client. If the singleton object does not exist, the SDK instantiates the default service client with `defaultServiceConfiguration` from `AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager()`. The reference to this object is maintained by the SDK, and you do not need to retain it manually.
     @return The default service client.
     */ 

    public class func `default`() -> SVTLambdaGateClient{
        return _defaultClient
    }

    /**
     Creates a service client with the given service configuration and registers it for the key.
     @param configuration A service configuration object.
     @param key           A string to identify the service client.
     */

    public class func registerClient(withConfiguration configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration, forKey key: String){
        _serviceClients.setObject(SVTLambdaGateClient(configuration: configuration), forKey: key  as NSString);
    }

    /**
     Retrieves the service client associated with the key. You need to call `registerClient(withConfiguration:configuration, forKey:)` before invoking this method or alternatively, set the configuration in your application's `info.plist` file. If `registerClientWithConfiguration(configuration, forKey:)` has not been called in advance or if a configuration is not present in the `info.plist` file of the app, this method returns `nil`.
     Then call the following to get the service client:

        let serviceClient = SVTLambdaGateClient.client(forKey: "USWest2SVTLambdaGateClient")

     @param key A string to identify the service client.
     @return An instance of the service client.
     */
    public class func client(forKey key: String) -> SVTLambdaGateClient {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        if let client: SVTLambdaGateClient = _serviceClients.object(forKey: key) as? SVTLambdaGateClient {
            objc_sync_exit(self)
            return client
        }

        let serviceInfo = AWSInfo.default().defaultServiceInfo(AWSInfoClientKey)
        if let serviceInfo = serviceInfo {
            let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: serviceInfo.region, credentialsProvider: serviceInfo.cognitoCredentialsProvider)
            SVTLambdaGateClient.registerClient(withConfiguration: serviceConfiguration!, forKey: key)
        }
        objc_sync_exit(self)
        return _serviceClients.object(forKey: key) as! SVTLambdaGateClient;
    }

    /**
     Removes the service client associated with the key and release it.

     @param key A string to identify the service client.
     */
    public class func removeClient(forKey key: String) -> Void{
        _serviceClients.remove(key)
    }

    init(configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration) {
        super.init()

        self.configuration = configuration.copy() as! AWSServiceConfiguration
        var URLString: String = "https://<my-api-id>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test"
        if URLString.hasSuffix("/") {
            URLString = URLString.substring(to: URLString.index(before: URLString.endIndex))
        }
        self.configuration.endpoint = AWSEndpoint(region: configuration.regionType, service: .APIGateway, url: URL(string: URLString))
        let signer: AWSSignatureV4Signer = AWSSignatureV4Signer(credentialsProvider: configuration.credentialsProvider, endpoint: self.configuration.endpoint)
        if let endpoint = self.configuration.endpoint {
            self.configuration.baseURL = endpoint.url
        }
        self.configuration.requestInterceptors = [AWSNetworkingRequestInterceptor(), signer]
    }

    /*


     @param operand2 
     @param _operator 
     @param operand1 

     return type: Empty
     */
    public func calcGet(operand2: String, _operator: String, operand1: String) -> AWSTask<Empty> {
        let headerParameters = [
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Accept": "application/json",

                ]

        var queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]
        queryParameters["operand2"] = operand2
        queryParameters["operator"] = _operator
        queryParameters["operand1"] = operand1

        let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

        return self.invokeHTTPRequest("GET", urlString: "/calc", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: Empty.self) as! AWSTask<Empty>
    }


    /*


     @param body 

     return type: Empty
     */
    public func calcPost(body: SVTInput) -> AWSTask<Empty> {
        let headerParameters = [
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Accept": "application/json",

                ]

        let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

        let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

        return self.invokeHTTPRequest("POST", urlString: "/calc", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: body, responseClass: Empty.self) as! AWSTask<Empty>
    }


    /*


     @param operand2 
     @param _operator 
     @param operand1 

     return type: SVTResult
     */
    public func calcOperand1Operand2OperatorGet(operand2: String, _operator: String, operand1: String) -> AWSTask<SVTResult> {
        let headerParameters = [
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Accept": "application/json",

                ]

        let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

        var pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]
        pathParameters["operand2"] = operand2
        pathParameters["operator"] = _operator
        pathParameters["operand1"] = operand1

        return self.invokeHTTPRequest("GET", urlString: "/calc/{operand1}/{operand2}/{operator}", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: SVTResult.self) as! AWSTask<SVTResult>
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Amplify team (who maintain and develop the AWS iOS SDK) verified that the [documentation is incorrect](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1357). It should reference `default()` and not `defaultClient()`.